# How to merge with two objects into a tuple with the two elements?

Tags: python, concatenation

I'm new to python and I was trying to merge two objects into a tuple with the two elements?

I've tried like merging lists, summing them and so on, nothing worked as I wanted. The code I'm providing doesn`t works also.

```
def merge(dict1,dict2):
    for key in dict2:
            if key in dict1:
                dict2[key]=dict2[key]+dict1[key]
            else:
                pass
    return dict2
```

The input is this:

```
a = {'x': [1,2,3], 'y': 1, 'z': set([1,2,3]), 'w': 'qweqwe', 't': {'a': [1, 2]}, 'm': [1]}
```

And this:

```
b = {'x': [4,5,6], 'y': 4, 'z': set([4,2,3]), 'w': 'asdf', 't': {'a': [3, 2]}, 'm': "wer"}
```

And I want the output to be this:

```
{'x': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'y': 5, 'z': set([1,2,3,4]), 'w': 'qweqweasdf', 't': {'a': [1, 2, 3, 2]}, 'm': ([1], "wer")}
```

With ^this being a single tuple.

Comment: These are not just objects (or tuples...). Those are [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given there are so many types, a lot of type checking is required, but this simple recursion should work.

Also, this assumes the keys in `a` and `b` are the same, as they are in the example.

```
def merge(a,b,new_dict):
    for key in a.keys():
        if type(a[key]) != type(b[key]):
            new_dict[key] = (a[key],b[key])
        elif type(a[key]) == dict:
            new_dict[key] = merge(a[key],b[key],{})
        elif type(a[key]) == set:
            new_dict[key] = a[key]|b[key]
        else:
            new_dict[key] = a[key] + b[key]
    return new_dict

c = merge(a,b,{})
```